# Compile a count of similar rows in a Pandas Dataframe based on multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, series

I have two Dataframes, one containing my data read in from a CSV file and another that has the data grouped by all of the columns but the last and reindexed to contain a column for the count of the size of the groups.

```
df_k1 = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
columns_for_groups = list(df_k1.columns)[:-1]
k1_grouped = df_k1.groupby(columns_for_groups).size().reset_index(name="Count")
```

I need to create a series such that every row(i) in the series corresponds to row(i) in my original Dataframe but the contents of the series need to be the size of the group that the row belongs to in the grouped Dataframe. I currently have this, and it works for my purposes, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a faster or more elegant solution.

```
size_by_row = []
for row in df_k1.itertuples():
    for group in k1_grouped.itertuples():
        if row[1:-1] == group[1:-1]:
            size_by_row.append(group[-1])
            break
group_size = pd.Series(size_by_row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).

Here's an example. I have a dataset of weather data.

```
>>> print(df.head())
         Date      Time  Temperature  Wind  WinSpeed
0  2002-01-01  12:53 AM           19   ENE        14
1  2002-01-02  12:53 AM           10    SE         5
2  2002-01-04  12:53 AM           30     W         9
3  2002-01-05  12:53 AM           25  CALM         0
4  2002-01-06  12:53 AM           23   SSE        13
...
```

For each observation, I want to know how many times the wind has been blowing in the same direction.

You can get this by using a `groupby()`, and calling `size()` on each group:

```
>>> df.groupby('Wind').size()
Wind
CALM     6549
E        8490
ENE      5401
ESE      5783
N        9511
NE       5881
NNE      5963
NNW      4824
NW       4161
S       14361
SE       6192
SSE      9202
SSW     13303
SW      15154
VAR      5565
W        9976
WNW      5104
WSW      9616
dtype: int64
```

...but we want to relate this back to each row.

That's where transform comes in.

```
>>> df['wind_size'] = df.groupby('Wind').transform('size')
>>> print(df.head())
         Date      Time  Temperature  Wind  WinSpeed  wind_size
0  2002-01-01  12:53 AM           19   ENE        14     5401.0
1  2002-01-02  12:53 AM           10    SE         5     6192.0
2  2002-01-04  12:53 AM           30     W         9     9976.0
3  2002-01-05  12:53 AM           25  CALM         0     6549.0
4  2002-01-06  12:53 AM           23   SSE        13     9202.0
```